# Retrieve only rows whose type is 're' and not 'res'

Tags: mysql

I want to get only those rows whose type is only 're' and not 'res' i.e output in the below example will be 2 and 4.

Table structure and data

```
Id  type
1    res
1    req
2    req
3    res
3    req
3    res
4    req
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM   demo AS A 
INNER JOIN demo AS B 
        ON B.id = A.id 
WHERE  type = "req"
```

But I'm not getting the proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That gets you all `id`s having only `req` entries

```
Select id 
from demo
group by id
having sum(type <> 'req') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not in

```
Select id from demo 
where id not in (select id from demo where type !="req" )
```